# Cannot install bluetooth

Tags: software-installation, bluetooth

After installing the Bluetooth package I got the following errors:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 7 package 'tesseract-ocr-epo':
 missing description
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 7 package 'tesseract-ocr-epo':
 missing maintainer
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 7 package 'tesseract-ocr-epo':
 missing version
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

After the installation I'll run the following to get the status.

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth status
response of the PI is:
-bash: /etc/init.d/bluetooth: No such file or directory
```

What can I do?

Comment: How did you install this?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy tesseract-ocr-epo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the commands below to remove `/var/lib/dpkg/available` and recreate

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
for i in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do sudo dpkg --merge-avail "$i"; done
```

Now install the package again.

Comment: This was the solution. Bluetooth works now fine. Thanks